# Object in the same position as another object has a different transform position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, blender

I have some objects that I have imported from blender as im attempting to make a destruction based game where an object once hit will be deactivated and replaced with its broken / collapsible counterpart. The problem I am experiencing is that when the script deactivates the 'together' object and activates the 'broken' object it is supposed to have the exact same transform position. However once the 'broken' object is activated it is in the wrong position. When inspecting the objects in Unity they are in the same position however the transform position for the objects is different:

[image: Sphere cell A transform position]

[image: Broken sphere cell A transform position]

Below is my script which i've taken from [here](https://github.com/williambl/unity-destruction) and i have only modified it so that when the "Snowball" object hits it will trigger the swap between the 'together' and broken' objects.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Destruction : MonoBehaviour {

[Header("Game Objects")]
[Space(2)]
[Tooltip("The broken gameObject")]
public GameObject brokenObj; // Set to igloo_broken_a object
[Tooltip("The unbroken gameObject")]
public GameObject togetherObj; // Set to Sphere_cell_A objcet
//private Rigidbody togetherObjRb;

[Space(7)]
[Header("State")]
[Space(2)]
[Tooltip("Whether the object is unbroken")]
public bool together = true;
[Tooltip("Whether the object starts broken")]
public bool startBroken = false;

[Space(7)]
[Header("Breaking on Collision")]
[Space(2)]
[Tooltip("Whether the object breaks when it collides with something")]
public bool breakOnCollision = true;
[Tooltip("The minimum relative velocity to break the object")]
public float velocityToBreak = 1; // Velocity required to break object

[Space(7)]
[Header("Breaking when nothing underneath")]
[Space(2)]
[Tooltip("Whether the object breaks when there's nothing underneath supporting it")]
public bool breakOnNoSupports = false;
[Tooltip("The length of the raycast used to check for supports underneath")]
public float raycastLength = 1f;

[Space(7)]
[Header("Sound On Break")]
[Space(2)]
[Tooltip("Whether the object makes a sound when it breaks")]
public bool soundOnBreak = false;
[Tooltip("An array of sounds for the object to make when it breaks (A random one will be selected)")]
public AudioClip[] clips;

[Space(7)]
[Header("Particles On Break")]
[Space(2)]
[Tooltip("Whether the object makes particles when it breaks")]
public bool particlesOnBreak = false;

//Private vars
private AudioSource src;
private ParticleSystem psys;
   /* [SerializeField] private float offsetX =41.807335f;
[SerializeField] private float offsetY = 10.52f;
[SerializeField] private float offsetZ = 28.67086f;
   */

void Start () {
    //Make sure the right object is active
    togetherObj.SetActive(!startBroken);
    brokenObj.SetActive(startBroken);
    together = !startBroken;
    //togetherObjRb = togetherObj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
   // togetherObjRb.useGravity = false;
    if (soundOnBreak)
        SetupSound();
    if (particlesOnBreak)
        SetupParticles();

}

void SetupSound() {
    //Get the audio source or create one
    src = brokenObj.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    if (src == null)
        src = brokenObj.AddComponent<AudioSource>();

    //Add a random audio clip to it
    src.clip = clips[Random.Range(0, clips.Length-1)];
}

void SetupParticles() {
    // Get the particle system or create one
    psys = brokenObj.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
    if (psys == null)
        psys = brokenObj.AddComponent<ParticleSystem>();

    //This doesn't seem to do anything b/c the gameobject is not active
    psys.Stop();
}

void Update () {
    /* Broken object should follow unbroken one to prevent them from
     * being in the wrong place when they switch */
    brokenObj.transform.position = togetherObj.transform.position;
    //brokenObj.transform.position = new Vector3(togetherObj.transform.position.x-offsetX , togetherObj.transform.position.y-offsetY,togetherObj.transform.position.z+offsetZ);
    Debug.Log("Broken transform: "+brokenObj.transform.position);
    Debug.Log("Together transform: "+togetherObj.transform.position);

    //Make sure the right object is active
    togetherObj.SetActive(together);
    brokenObj.SetActive(!together);

    if (breakOnNoSupports)
        CheckForSupports();
}

void CheckForSupports () {
    //Check downwards for supports
    if (!Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, raycastLength))
        Break();
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    if (!breakOnCollision)
        return;
    //Only break if relative velocity is high enough
    //if (collision.relativeVelocity.magnitude > velocityToBreak && collision.gameObject.name != "Cylinder" && collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Snowball")){
    if (collision.relativeVelocity.magnitude > velocityToBreak && collision.gameObject.name != "Cylinder"){
        //togetherObj.SetActive(false);
        Break();
    }
   
}

public void Break () {
    together = false;

    //Play the sound
    if (soundOnBreak)
        src.Play();
    //Show particles
    if (particlesOnBreak)
        psys.Play();
}

public void BreakWithExplosiveForce(float force, float radius = 3) {
    Break();

    //Add the explosive force to each rigidbody
    foreach (Rigidbody rigid in brokenObj.GetComponentsInChildren<Rigidbody>())
        rigid.AddExplosionForce(force, transform.position, radius);
}

}
```

Because of this when playing the game and the script is triggered by a collision, the 'broken' object is not in the same transform position as the 'together' object was:

[image: Broken object not in the same position as the together]

Things i have tried:

1. Changing the scene 'Tool Handle Position; from center to pivot, and back again
2. Adding an offset to the 'broken' objects transform position, this would work i think if i fiddled with it enough but i dont think it should even be necessary.
   3.I have also review the origins of the objects im using in blender, and it looks like they are identical:
   [image: together object blender origin]
   [image: broken object blender origin]
3. I have done additional testing using a different 'broken' object than the one in the above example, and this one is activated in the correct location, so it must be something to do with the object itself, however checking on blender i can see that the origin point is the same as the 'together' object (see above images for orgins).
   [image]

Comment: Values in the Inspector are **local positions** => relative to according parent object's space => Are your objects under different parent objects? Also you have selected (Geometric)`Center` for the cursor position .. can you change that to `Pivot`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the object origin in blender. After going into blender and then pressing ALT+G before exporting each broken piece individually, the central point of the object was corrected.
[image: Previous object central point]

[image: New central point]

Now the transform works correctly and it actually performs the destruction behaviour im after:

[image: Destruction in correct location]

Answer (score 1):

From the hierarchy windows, it is clear that either both the objects are at root or children of the same parent object, so the chances of the problem arising due to world position or local position are minimal.

Since you said the meshes are imported from blender, it seems to be a problem of "geometric origin" of the mesh. Like I have designed these two cubes in blender, one has origin at centre, other at one of the vertices.

[image: Cube with origin at centre]

[image: Cube with origin at one of the vertices]

So, when I import them into Unity, although they appear at the same position in scene, the position of their origin is different, just like in your case.

You will be able to see the true origin position of your models by changing the centre option to pivot.

[image: Position of cube with origin at a vertex]

[image: Position of cube with origin at centre]

Also, there seems to be some problem with the up and forward axis configurations while exporting the models from blender which is evident by the orientation of transform lines and the rotation of the models in your images.

By the way, please ignore the scale of 100, I forgot to reset the scale in blender after making some models for UE5.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've just checked and it seems that the objects that i imported from blender both seem to have the same origin

Comment: then maybe it is due to the mismatched rotation, you see there is a difference of about 90 degrees along x-axis

Comment: Unfortunately changing the rotation didnt put it in the same location as the together object. Im beginning to think i should just make the broken objects again in blender and re-import them to see if this resolves the issue.